# Ambiguous dependencies for type

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, cdi, managed-bean

I am getting this exception when I try deploying my application to Glassfish Server:

> org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001409 Ambiguous
>   dependencies for type [FileReferenceDao] with qualifiers [@Default] at
>   injection point [[BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject
>   com.tugay.fup.web.MyUploadedFilesBean.fileReferenceDao]. Possible
>   dependencies [[Session bean [class
>   com.tugay.fup.core.dao.FileReferenceDao with qualifiers [@Any
>   @Default]; local interfaces are [FileReferenceDao], Session bean
>   [class com.tugay.fup.core.dao.FileReferenceDao with qualifiers [@Any
>   @Default]; local interfaces are [FileReferenceDao]]]

The interesting part is

> Possible dependencies [[Session bean [class
>   com.tugay.fup.core.dao.FileReferenceDao with qualifiers [@Any
>   @Default]; local interfaces are [FileReferenceDao], Session bean
>   [class com.tugay.fup.core.dao.FileReferenceDao with qualifiers [@Any
>   @Default]; local interfaces are [FileReferenceDao]]]

What is going on in here?

I only have one FileReferenceDao, which has no Interface or anything else. It does not extend any other class. And this is how I use it:

```
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Named
@RequestScoped
public class MyUploadedFilesBean {

    @Inject
    FileReferenceDao fileReferenceDao;
```

Everything was working fine until 15 minutes ago.

I tried mixing JSF Managed beans with CDI beans, it did not work, I rolled - back. Now I am getting this exception.

```
@Stateless public class FileReferenceDao {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "Persistence")
    EntityManager em;
```

Comment: What version of glassfish are you using? Can you try annotating the EJB as `@LocalBean` ?

Comment: @JohnAment The interesting thing is I can not reproduce this always. Glassfish - 4. I am still investigating what causes it.

Comment: Hello. Annotating FileReferenceDao with LocalBean did not help. It happens some times.. Sometimes deployments is fine. I do not understand how this is possible.

Comment: Changing from Inject to EJB solved the problem. I have no idea what is going on in here..

Comment: Thanks for confirming GF4.  I would actually raise this as a bug against GF4.  This should work fine.

Comment: Sorry, what should work fine? @JohnAment

Comment: `@Inject FileReferenceDao fileReferenceDao;` should work fine if it's an EJB.  Based on the error you're describing, GF4 is not able to process the beans properly.

Comment: Yeah, Inject is not working. @EJB works. Strange. It works sometimes when I use Inject annotation. I can't really tell.